# Cannot find module 'react/lib/ReactCurrentOwner' from 'ReactFiberTreeReflection.js'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I trying to start unit test in react-native folowing this [jest tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react-native.html). But when i run `npm test` i get the error `Cannot find module 'react/lib/ReactCurrentOwner' from 'ReactFiberTreeReflection.js'`

My Component is the most simple as possible

```
// /SimpleComp.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
} from 'react-native';

export default class SimpleComp extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View></View>
        );
    }
}
```

And here are my test file

```
// /__tests__/SimpleComp-test.js
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import SimpleComp from '../SimpleComp';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

test('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
        <SimpleComp />
    ).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

### Full test output

```
 FAIL  __tests__/SimpleComp-test.js
    ● Test suite failed to run

        Cannot find module 'react/lib/ReactCurrentOwner' from 'ReactFiberTreeReflection.js'

        at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:169:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactFiberTreeReflection.js:15:25)

    Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
    Tests:       0 total
    Snapshots:   0 total
    Time:        0.42s
    Ran all test suites.
    npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

### Aditional info

#### Versions

react-native:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.45.1
```

yarn: v0.27.5

npm: 3.10.10

node: v6.11.1

#### Package.json

```json
{
    "name": "PrimeiraMesa2",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest",
        "flow": "flow"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.16.2",
        "jest-haste-map": "^20.0.4",
        "moment": "^2.18.1",
        "native-base": "2.2.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
        "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
        "react-devtools-core": "^2.3.3",
        "react-native": "0.45.1",
        "react-native-check-box": "^1.0.4",
        "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
        "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.3.3",
        "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.6.0",
        "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.2.12",
        "react-native-gps-state": "git+https://github.com/neuberoliveira/react-native-gps-state.git",
        "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.3",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.2.9",
        "react-native-linear-gradient": "react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient",
        "react-native-masked-text": "^1.5.1",
        "react-native-modal": "^2.4.0",
        "react-native-multiple-select": "^0.2.1",
        "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.134",
        "react-native-onesignal": "^3.0.5",
        "react-native-push-notification": "^3.0.0",
        "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.6.7",
        "react-native-star-rating": "^1.0.7",
        "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.4",
        "react-native-textinput-effects": "git+https://github.com/multisolution/react-native-textinput-effects",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.1",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
        "redux": "^3.7.2",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
        "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.9",
        "underscore": "^1.8.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
        "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
        "eslint": "^4.4.1",
        "jest": "19.0.2",
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that you've run `npm install`, right? If you have, try deleting the `node_modules` folder and rerunning `npm install`.

Comment: Already did this a few times, same result

Comment: Try referencing [this issue](https://github.com/dalcib/jest-expo-ts/issues/1) on GitHub. Could have some useful info.

Comment: tried that issue too,mainly the `import *` things (dont use expo), same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve my own question.

I did not create the project, i get the project in the middle, so i install a fresh version of react-native 0.45, the same my project was using, and i discover that the jest versions in the `package.json devDependencies` are mismatching.

Here are my project `devDependencies`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
},
```

Here the `devDependencies` of the fresh install

```
"devDependencies": {
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "21.0.2",
    "jest": "21.1.0"
},
```

Seems the project was updated.

After that i install everything again `rm -rf node_modules && yarn install`

Running `npm test` again the test pass as expected.

Comment: I had a similar error when my react and react-dom version were not matching.